# Complete list of pod statuses

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When you run "kubectl get pods -A -o wide" you get a list of pods and a STATUS column.

Where can I get a list of the possible status options?

What I trying to do is generate a list of statuses and how many pods are in each status. If I had a list of the possible status states I could do what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope this helps `kubectl get pod -A --no-headers |awk '{arr[$4]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}'`

Comment: the url https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase will explain the pod phases, which may be bit different from what we see in `kubectl get po` output.

Answer (score 2):

*kubectl* summarizes the status of pods as follows:

1. It is the `pod.status.phase` (e.g. Running)
2. If the `pod.status.reason` is not empty, then it is used (e.g. Evicted)
3. If the `pod.status.conditions` contains a type `PodScheduled` with reason `WaitingForGates`, then it is set to `SchedulingGated`
4. Then the `pod.status.initContainerStatuses` are taken into account (if there are any)
5. Then the `pod.status.containerStatuses` are taken into account where it is set to a **Waiting**, **Terminated** or **Completed** state. The **Completed** state is mapped to `Running` or `NotReady` if at least one container in a pod is running.
6. Lastly, the pod might be deleted (e.g. `Terminating`) or deleted and unreachable (e.g. `Unknown`)

I just tried to summarize the code in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.27.2/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L816.

### Values in pod status API

[Pod Phases](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.27.2/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L2514) (`pod.status.phase`) are:

- `Pending`
- `Running`
- `Succeeded`
- `Failed`
- `Unknown` (deprecated since v1.21)

[Pod Condition Types](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.27.2/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L2538) (`pod.status.conditions.type`) are:

- `PodScheduled`
- `Ready`
- `Initialized`
- `ContainersReady`
- `DisruptionTarget`

Answer (score 1):

like comment in [Complete list of pod statuses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035324/complete-list-of-pod-statuses#comment122014046_69035324) :

```sh
$ kubectl get pod -A --no-headers |awk '{arr[$4]++}END{for (a in arr) print a, arr[a]}'

Evicted 1
Running 121
CrashLoopBackOff 4
Completed 5
Pending 1
```

This command will shows how many pod are currently in what state.

But how to get the possible values of all the states?

In my view, there is no api or command to get it.
This status: "The aggregate status of the containers in this pod." source code can be find in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/printers/internalversion/printers.go#L741 shows `status` based on `pod.Status.Phase` and will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want also result on container basics, you try this command

```
kubectl get pods -A -o wide --no-headers | cut -b 85-108 | sort | uniq -c
```

if the output looks like

> ```
>  2   0/1   CrashLoopBackOff
>   1   0/3   Pending
> 260   1/1   Running
>   4   2/2   Running
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A phase of a  [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/) is a simple, high-level summary of  where the Pod is in its    Lifecycle.

The phase is not intended to be a comprehensive rollup of observations of Container or Pod state, nor is it intended to be a comprehensive state machine.
Here are the possible values for phase:

**Pending** The Pod has been accepted by the Kubernetes system, but one or more of the Container images has not been created. This includes time before being scheduled as well as time spent downloading images over the network, which could take a while.

**Running** The Pod has been bound to a node, and all the Containers have been created. At least one Container is still running, or is working on starting or restarting.

**Succeeded** All Containers in the Pod have terminated in success, and will not be restarted.

**Failed** All Containers in the Pod have terminated, and at least one Container has terminated in failure. That is, the Container either exited with non-zero status or was terminated by the system.

**Unknown** For some reason the state of the Pod could not be obtained, typically due to an error in communicating with the host of the Pod.

If you are interested in detailed arrays with Pod conditions, I suggest looking at  [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle#pod-phase) from Kubernetes documentation and inspect  [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/events/event.go) for remaining information.